# conditional variable in main thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In my main thread, I am trying to wait for two resources from two separate threads. The way I implemented is as below:

```
require 'thread'

def new_thread
    Thread.current[:ready_to_go] = false
    puts "in thread: new thread"
    sleep(5)
    puts "in thread: sleep finished"
    Thread.current[:ready_to_go] = true
    sleep(2)
    puts "in thread: back to thread again!"
end


thread1 = Thread.new do
    new_thread
end

thread2 = Thread.new do
    new_thread
end

# the main thread wait for ready_to_go to start
while (!(thread1[:ready_to_go] && thread2[:ready_to_go]))
    sleep(0.5)
end
puts "back to main!"
sleep(8)
puts "main sleep over!"

thread1.join
thread2.join
```

Is there any better way to implement this? I tried to use conditional variables: the two threads signal the conditional variables and the main thread waits for them. But the wait method requires a mutex in my main thread, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but [the first Google result for "Ruby wait for thread"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html) says:

> you can wait for a particular thread to finish by calling that thread's Thread#join method. The calling thread will block until the given thread is finished. By calling join on each of the requestor threads, you can make sure that all three requests have completed before you terminate the main program.

It's generally best to use synchronization methods to wait for something to complete, rather than looping until a particular state is reached.

Comment: The main thread is not waiting for the other threads to join back. It is waiting for some resources to be ready (Thread.current[:ready_to_go]). The threads need to keep running when the main thread begins to run.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  The normal way I would implement this is to create an event corresponding to each thread, wait for said event in the main thread, and signal the corresponding event in each spawned thread when it's ready to go.  However, it appears that Ruby's only synchronization mechanism is the Mutex, so it you may have to rig up something with Mutex and ConditionalVariable.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to get a Queue (let's call it `myqueue`). It's threadsafe and located in the Thread module

Instead of

```
Thread.current[:ready_to_go] = true
```

... do

```
myqueue.push :ready_to_go
```

And then your main thread would be:

```
junk = myqueue.pop # wait for thread one to push
junk = myqueue.pop # wait for thread two to push
# go on with your work
```